# Generate missing values on the dataset based on ZIPF distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, zipf

Currently, I want to observe the impact of missing values on my dataset. I replace data point (10, 20, 90 %) to missing values and observe the impact. This function below is to replace a certain per cent data point to missing.

```
def dropout(df, percent):
    # create df copy
    mat = df.copy()
    # number of values to replace
    prop = int(mat.size * percent)
    # indices to mask
    mask = random.sample(range(mat.size), prop)
    # replace with NaN
    np.put(mat, mask, [np.NaN]*len(mask))
    return mat
```

My question is, I want to replace missing values based on zipf distirbution/power low/long tail. For instance, I have a dataset that contains of 10 columns (5 columns categorical data and 5 columns numerical data). I want to replace some data points on 5 columns categorical based on zipf law, columns in the left sides have more missing rather than in the right side.

I used Python to do this task.

I saw Scipy manual about zipf distirbution in this link: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.zipf.html but still it's not help me much.

Answer (score 0):

Zipf distributions are a family of distributions on 0 to infinity, whereas you want to delete values from only 5 discrete columns, so you will have to make some arbitrary decisions to do this. Here is one way:

1. Pick a parameter for your Zipf distribution, say a = 2 as in the example given on the [SciPy documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.zipf.html).
2. Looking at the plot given on that same page, you could decide to truncate at 10, i.e. if any sampled value of more than 10 comes up, you're just going to discard it.
3. Then you could just map the remaining domain of 0 to 10 linearly to your five categorical columns: Any value between 0 and 2 corresponds to the first column, and so on.

So you iteratively sample single values from your Zipf distribution using the SciPy function. For every sampled value, you delete one data point in the column the value corresponds to (see 3.), until you have reached the overall desired percentage of missing values.